# using Nest DateRange

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Using [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html) example, I came up with the following query.  I don't get any results from this, but if I replace "01/01/2017" with 'null' then I get records (all from 2014 so i know it should be returning data).  Can anyone help me please?

```
 var response = elasticClient.Search<AnalyticsFormData>(x => x
       .Type("formdata")
       .Size(500)
       .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must
              (mu => mu.MatchPhrase(m => m
          .Field(f => f.AppId)
              .Query(input.FormAppId)))
           .Filter(fi => fi
           .DateRange(r => r
           .Field(f => f.LastUpdated)
           .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored("01/01/2017"))))))              
           .Sort(s => s.Ascending(f => f.LastUpdated)));
```

Comment: In which format your date values are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have an incorrect field mapping, or incorrect date format. Try the following:

1. Create a new index with automapping

   ```
   elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName,
       create => create.Mappings(
           mappings => mappings.Map<AnalyticsFormData>(map => map.AutoMap())
       )
   );
   ```
2. Use the following approach to set the date

   ```
   var response = client.Search<AnalyticsFormData>(x => x
       .Size(500)
       .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must
           (mu => mu.MatchPhrase(m => m
       .Field(f => f.AppId).Query("FormAppId")))
       .Filter(fi => fi
       .DateRange(r => r
       .Field(f => f.LastUpdated)
       .LessThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2017, 1, 1))))))
       .Sort(s => s.Ascending(f => f.LastUpdated)));
   ```

Comment: thanks that works, I thought the DateMath.Anchored parameter wanted a string, but turns out it wants a datetime object.

Comment: `DateMath.Anchored()` can take either a `string` or `DateTime`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Nest/CommonOptions/DateMath/DateMath.cs#L33-L34

Comment: ok, well it doesn't work with a string for me for some reason using format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: what format should the string be in then for it to work?  Because I'm trying all different ones without success.

Comment: @Jynn the `string` format used will by default need to be a valid one for the `format` used on the `date` field you are targeting. If you want to pass a different date format in the query then you need to specify `format` in the query too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_format_in_range_queries Essentially, Elasticsearch needs to know how to parse the string passed into a Date object on the server side.